# Suppressing Line in section crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

```
Hi All I have a report having two sub reports
In 1st sub report i have a line in report header and footer.
And in 2nd sub report i have a line in report header and footer.
```

So My 2 sub reports are coming one after other.In this case i am getting two lines
one after other(one from sub report 1 footer and other from sub report 2 header)
Now i need to suppress the line in 1st sub report when there is a 2nd sub report fallowed it

Comment: Do you have any conditions to hide or show your subreports?  And do you want to always hide the footer from SubRpt 1 or conditionally?

Answer (score 0):

```
I have not tried this solution but I think it will help.

    1] Create a global variable in your second sub report. 
    2] Set its counter to 0 and increment its value with the number of rows you are getting in  2nd sub report. 
    3] On 1st sub report go to format sub report and in suppress formula check whether global variable is greater than 0 if yes then it will suppress 1st sub report.

Not sure with the execution flow of crystal reports but its worth giving a try. let me know if you succeed.

Thanks,
Pratik
```